# Best way to get all string comes after "?" in url in spring webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I need to extract all the string that comes after "?" in spring webflux. Basically if request was

```
http://localhost:8080/test?some=query|test=whatever,|something
```

I want to extract

```
some=query|test=whatever,|something
```

as one string value. Here is what I am doing:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<String> test(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest) {
    String uri = serverHttpRequest.getURI().toString();
    String queryParam = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("?") + 1);
    return Mono.just(queryParam);
}
```

It does work, but I want to know if there is better or cleaner way to write this code.

UPDATE:
I found that this is little better:

```
String queryParam = serverHttpRequest.getUri().getRawQuery();
```

Comment: How about using `serverHttpRequest.getQueryParams()`?

Comment: I think that requires a "key" which returns value from the query. In my case, I want all the string comes after "?"

Comment: You might try: `String.join("&", serverHttpRequest.getQueryParams())` or `serverHttpRequest.getQuereyParams().stream(.collect(Collectors.joining("&"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use getRawQuery instead to get the original string after the ? sign

```
request.getURI().getRawQuery()
```

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uri-getrawquery-method-in-java-with-examples/

As an alternative option to have a look into you could get all of the parameters as a map using

```
@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams
```

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Comment: Ah, true, I fixed the answer, thanks! 
Trying it out using Kotlin set me up :)

Comment: I think first answer is the one I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Unmitigated the `exchange.request.uri`(kotlin) in reactive request does not return the query param part here.